# what's different between StrCmpW and wcscmp?

Tags: linux, unicode, strcmp, qsort, wstring

---

Actually i changed code to next.

---

```
struct myclass {
    bool operator() (std::wstring p1, std::wstring p2) {
        int result = 0;
        //// If character is alphabet, sorting need converse.
        wint_t a1 = p1.at(0);
        wint_t b2 = p2.at(0);
        int r1 = iswalpha(a1);
        int r2 = iswalpha(b2);
        **// return code of iswalpha.
        // 257 is Upper Alphabet, 
        // 258 is Lower Alphabet**
        if ((r1 == 257 && r1 == 258) || 
            (r2 == 258 && r2 == 257)) {
            result = p2.compare(p1);
        }
        else {
            result = p1.compare(p2);
        }   

        if (result != 0) {
            if (result == -1) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
} wStrCompare;

void main() {
    std::vector<std::wstring> wlist;
    wlist.emplace_back(L"가나");
    wlist.emplace_back(L"123");
    wlist.emplace_back(L"abc");
    wlist.emplace_back(L"타파");
    wlist.emplace_back(L"하하");
    wlist.emplace_back(L"!@#$");
    wlist.emplace_back(L"一二三");
    wlist.emplace_back(L"好好");
    wlist.emplace_back(L"QWERID");
    wlist.emplace_back(L"ⓐⓑ");
    wlist.emplace_back(L"☆★");
    wlist.emplace_back(L"とばす");

    std::sort(wlist.begin(), wlist.end(), wStrCompare);
}
```

---

### Test Result

```
L"!@#$"
L"123"
L"abc"
L"QWERID"
L"ⓐⓑ"
L"☆★"
L"とばす"
L"一二三"
L"好好"
L"가나"
L"타파"
L"하하"
```

---

is this good?
Please give me a some opinion.

Thanks!!

---

### I change my code, but i still want to know "*is there difference between StrCmpW and wcscmp*" Please talk to me. thanks!

---

### Old question

I use qsort with std::wstring(for unicode string), and use StrCmpW.

Previously, I used [StrCmpLogicalW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759947(v=vs.85).aspx)() with CString, [CStringArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tddz3etf.aspx).
(These are depend on windows)

But my code run in linux too, not only in windows.
(CString is ATL(afx), StrCmpLogicalW() is in Shlwapi.h)

So I use std::wstring and wcscmp, but result is different.

Is there a difference between StrCmpW() and wcscmp()?

### The Following is my code.(exactly not mine lol)

```
int wCmpName(const void* p1, const void *p2)
{
    std::wstring* wszName1 = ((std::wstring *)(p1));
    std::wstring* wszName2 = ((std::wstring *)(p2));

    int wret = StrCmpW(wszName1->c_str(), wszName2->c_str());
    // int wret = wcscmp(wszName1->c_str(), wszName2->c_str());
    // When i use wcscmp, different result comes out.
    return wret;
}

void wSort(std::vector<std::wstring> &arr)
{
    qsort(arr.data(), arr.size(), sizeof(std::wstring), wCmpName);
}
```

---

Thanks!

---

### Test Code

```
void main() {
    std::vector<std::wstring> wlist;
    wlist.emplace_back(L"가나");
    wlist.emplace_back(L"123");
    wlist.emplace_back(L"abc");
    wlist.emplace_back(L"타파");
    wlist.emplace_back(L"하하");
    wlist.emplace_back(L"!@#$");
    wlist.emplace_back(L"一二三");
    wlist.emplace_back(L"好好");
    wlist.emplace_back(L"QWERID");
    wlist.emplace_back(L"ⓐⓑ");
    wlist.emplace_back(L"☆★");
    wlist.emplace_back(L"とばす");

    wSort(wlist);
}
```

---

### Test Result

- wcscmp

  ```
  L"!@#$"
  L"123"
  L"QWERID"
  L"abc"
  L"ⓐⓑ"
  L"☆★"
  L"とばす"
  L"一二三"
  L"好好"
  L"가나"
  L"타파"
  L"하하"
  ```
- StrCmpW

  ```
  L"!@#$"
  L"☆★"
  L"123"
  L"ⓐⓑ"
  L"abc"
  L"QWERID"
  L"とばす"
  L"가나"
  L"一二三"
  L"타파"
  L"하하"
  L"好好"
  ```

---

p.s : WHY limit reputation?! limited Images, limited URLs.
      Only text takes so long time.

Comment: Can you provide an example of two strings that give different results for `StrCmpW()` and `wcscmp()`? There are also *many* other problems with that code...

Comment: use `std::sort` instead of `qsort`, and then you can get rid of the incredibly ugly casts.

Comment: @一二三 add test & result. please see again.

Comment: @BenVoigt that is good suggestion.i changed it, so be a better code.

Comment: `StrCmpW(L"☆★", L"123")` and `wcscmp(L"☆★", L"123")` both give me the same result (`1`).

Comment: @一二三 really? In my case, `StrCmpW(L"☆★", L"123")` return `1`, `wcscmp(L"☆★", L"123")` return `-1`.

Comment: There should be no difference between the functions, but it sounds like you're getting the source encoding or locale wrong...